Feasibility Question: Reducing Co2 emissions from Water based scrubber tanks from Bioreactors
In a bioreactor, organic waste is decomposed anaerobically, giving primarily Co2 and CH4. The CH4 is resold, but has to be seperated from the Co2. I undertand this is typically done using a water scrubbing tank. Where some Co2 disolves, and some becomes carbonic acid.
The addition of a base, like NaOH would fix the carbonic acid to a stable form, that could potentially could be recoverd and sold, but primarily, the fixing process should also help improve the seperation efficiency.
Although, I do assume that the water from the scrubbing tank is replaced periodically.
My question is on feasibility. Would the cost of the NaOH (or alternative base?) be offset by the seperation efficiency gains, and the resale of recoverd sodium bicarbonate?
Is this a new Idea, or is this what already happens in Bioreactors?


Note: I think that most commercial uses for Sodium Bicarbonate would result in the Co2 being released again, so it would be 'greener' to dump it rather than sell it.


Chemists cannot recognize Co2. This symbol is for two atoms of cobalt joined together. Is this what you meant?
